# why give a random number when log in setInterval

Tags: javascript

The code:

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    console.log(i);
}, 1000);
```

The output will be like this:

```
24 %Random number here%
0
0 %Always 0 as expected%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `setInterval()` returns a unique number. And not a random number.

This number is used in the function `clearInterval()`

Same is the case for `setTimeout()`

Comment: Yeah. I forget that. Damn It!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description of `window.setInterval`: [Window.setInterval on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval).

In console, it will output the return value of an expression. And the return value of `setInterval` is a `intervalID`. You can use the intervalID when call `clearInterval`.